# Nested loop with arrays having repeating numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I have an array that keeps the number of each element.

```
int total[5] = {2,3,4,5,6}
int num = 5; //array total has 5 elements
```

This means that we have 2 element 0's, 3 element 1's in our original array. We are not worried about the original array since I already have a code to keep the number of the elements.

I need a nested for loop that creates a new array that looks like this:

```
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 1;

array[2] = 5;
array[3] = 5;
array[4] = 5;

array[5] = 9;
array[6] = 9;
array[7] = 9;
array[8] = 9;
```

and so on. That is, we store a value in our new array as many as the its value in "total" array. Values 1,5,9, etc. are stored in an array called element. I have something like this so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
     for (int j = 0; j < total[i]; j++){
         array[i + j] = element[i];
     }
}
```

Can somebody help me to figure this out?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: As far as I understand, you're code should work. What is your question exactly ?

Comment: _"This means that we have 2 element 0's, 3 element 1's in our original array."_ Huh?

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution (though not necessarily elegant) is to do the following:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < total[i]; j++){
        array[count] = element[i];
        count++;
    }
}
```

then you don't need to worry about trying to figure out what position you are at for the array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the number of the elements:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
     for (int j = 0; j < total[i]; j++){
         array[sum + j] = element[i];
     }
     sum += total[i];
}
```